# format-table and properties that are arrays

Tags: powershell

i use this powershell command:

```
get-vm | ft name, *start*, *stop*, customproperties
```

that returns objects with a string array as a property (customproperties):

```
Name                StartAction DelayStart      StopAction CustomProperties
----                ----------- ----------      ---------- ----------------
TKAD4        AlwaysAutoTurnOnVM          0 ShutdownGuestOS {NoStartupDelay, ...
TKAD3        AlwaysAutoTurnOnVM          0 ShutdownGuestOS {NoStartupDelay, ...
```

how can i return just one element from an array the is a property as an object to display it as part of a table?

my desired output would look like this:

```
Name                StartAction DelayStart      StopAction        Custom1
----                ----------- ----------      ----------        -------
TKAD4        AlwaysAutoTurnOnVM          0 ShutdownGuestOS NoStartupDelay
TKAD3        AlwaysAutoTurnOnVM          0 ShutdownGuestOS NoStartupDelay
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Format-Table, change `customproperties` to either:

```
@{label='Custom1';e={$_.CustomProperties[0]}}
```

If it is an array.  If it is a collection use:

```
@{label='Custom1';e={$_.CustomProperties | Select -First 1}}
```